# Relay access denied error attempting to setup relay to another SMTP server

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server

I am attempting to setup 2 SMTP servers behind one firewall. One server for `domainA.com` and another for `domainB.com`. I want to configure the server for `domainA.com` to accept mail for `domainB.com` and forward it internally.

I have added the following setup in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` on domainA.com:

```
transport_maps =
    hash:/etc/postfix/transport
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_maillist.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf

relay_domains =
    $mydestination
    hash:/etc/postfix/relay
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf

relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients

relay_transport = relay
```

And in the referenced files:

`/etc/postfix/relay`

```
domainB.com
```

`/etc/postfix/relay_recipients`

```
@domainB.com x
```

`/etc/postfix/transport`

```
domainB.com     smtp:[192.168.0.236]
```

I have run `postmap` on each of these files.

Mail to/from `domainA.com` works fine. When I attempt to send mail to postmaster@domainB.com, it bounces with `554 5.7.1 <postmaster@domainB.com>: Relay access denied`

Comment: Is there anything in the logs on the domainB server?

Comment: Nothing from domainA's IP, just local mails being delivered from Cron jobs to the postmaster inbox.

Comment: I noticed I had received a warning when running `postmap` on `/etc/postfix/relay` about unexpected formatting, and now it appears I'm a step further. I changed it to `domainB.com x` and now I'm seeing the mail accepted and a connection open to the server for domainB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed I had received an error when running `postmap`:

```
postmap: warning: /etc/postfix/relay, line 1: expected format: key whitespace value
```

I changed the file to contain `domainB.com x` and re-ran `postmap`. It appears mail is now being accepted for relaying!